# low disk space due to its usage as tmpfs

Tags: 16.04, swap, disk-usage, tmpfs

I have ran a program and i just entered wrong dimensions (100 times larger) so it took all my disk space and even then it didnot ran and hang the system for 5 minutes. Now when I restared my system it is showing low disk space error. I am showing the df -h result

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           392M  6.2M  386M   2% /run
/dev/sda7        93G   88G  627M 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G   19M  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           392M   64K  392M   1% /run/user/1000
```

so how to delete all these partitions and get back the whole space.

thanks

Comment: How should we know where yours `a program` has written it's files ? Try to look in the directory where ypu atarted the program from, or directories below that.

Comment: Actually I was opening a pdf file in gimp with resolution 100 (i did 10000 instead) then all hang up...

Comment: ok... there is a directory .gimp-2.8 in my home which is 15gb... I think I should delete it

Comment: @InduBala Yes, that is definitely what you should delete. Note that this will reset your preferences in GIMP.